# Using JMeter, how to test performance, for a load of 100000 users?

Tags: jmeter, performance, load-testing

Using Jmeter, how to test performance, for a load of 100 thousand users?
I would deeply appreciate any help on this.

I put 100000 users in the thread and give 200000 ramp-up time. Is it working or not?

Answer (score 2):

1. First of all it is highly unlikely you will be able to spawn 100 000 virtual users using single JMeter instance so most probably you will have to go for [Distributed Testing](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html), it means that you will need to get several **JMeter Slaves** which will be orchestrated by **JMeter Master**
2. The number of virtual users which can be simulated from one host varies and depends on many factors, i.e. test nature (hardware specifications, request/response sizes, number of [samplers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers), number of [preprocessors](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#preprocessors)/[postprocessors](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors)/[assertions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#assertions), etc.) so you need to identify how [many users you will be able to simulate using JMeter from a single machine](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what%E2%80%99s-the-max-number-of-users-you-can-test-on-jmeter). Once you figure that out you will be able to calculate how many JMeter Slaves you need.
3. Always stick to [JMeter Best Practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html), i.e.

   - [Run your test in non-GUI mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui)
   - Use only those pre/post processors and assertions which are absolutely required
   - Disable or remove all the [Listeners](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/greedy-listeners-memory-leeches-performance-testing) during the test run as they don't add any value and consume a lot of resources.

Assuming all above you should be able to simulate 100 000 users. Just remember one thing: all JMeter Slaves are basically executing **the same test plan** so you will need to divide the total number of users by the number of JMeter Slaves, examples:

- 10 JMeter Slaves, each has 10 000 users - you will get 100 000 users
- 20 JMeter Slaves, each has 5 000 users - you will get 100 000 users
- etc.

Comment: Instead of answering new one, You may add a reference link to your previously answered question. 
https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/18522/how-to-conduct-a-performance-test-using-jmeter-for-100000-users